# Issue while installing Windows on separate drive, observed shared system and recovery partition

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, bootloader

[image]Issue while installing Windows on separate drive WITHOUT dual boot, shared system and recovery partition
I have 2 physical drives drive 1 and drive 2.

My drive 1 already has a Windows 10 (RS5/19H1) installed, and I want to install a Windows 10(RS5) on my drive 2.

on Driver 1, I can see for partitions:

- System
- Recovery
- MSR
- Primary

I first tried to boot from a USB stick and tried to install RS5 on the drive 2. It installed windows successfully,

now I See there are only 2 new partitions created that is Primary and MSR, and looks like OS loader got installed into System partition when I was installing OS on Driver 2.

Is it expected behavior of Windows? As this doesn't Allow to boot from Drive 2 alone, Drive 1 has to be present then only can boot from Drive 2.

OR need to install OS on each driver separately.

Is this known issue/feature with Windows OS installer? is there any documentation on this behavior from MS?

Partitions displayed after installing the OS:

```
drive0 - partition1: System
drive0 - partition2: Recovery
drive0 - partition3: MSR
drive0 - partition4: Primary
drive1 - partition1: MSR
drive1 - partition2: Primary
```

Comment: Can you find all programs (that you installed on windows drive 1) on windows drive 2 after booting ( with drive 1 attached of course) from drive 2 ?

Comment: what you means by programs? when I boot to OS installed on either driver, I see the other drive in OS.

Comment: By programs i mean any softwares or apps ;It will be helpful if you attach a screenshot of disk manager showing partitions of both drives

Comment: update the drives and partitions showed.

Comment: I think every thing here is normal.Recovery partition will be created automatically.See - https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/141419-windows-10-missing-recovery-partition.html No EFI sytem partition because you already have one See (a little related issue) - https://www.tenforums.com/installation-upgrade/52837-moving-recreating-efi-partition.html

Comment: means this is expected scenario? Is this documented somewhere in windows forum or microsoft articles?

Comment: Yup ! An  expected scenario ! And Google is your friend for that !!!

Comment: Not exact what you are looking for but will surely help - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions and a similar case - https://superuser.com/questions/1346293/im-confused-i-dont-have-an-efi-partition-in-my-drive-but-i-can-boot-windows

Comment: Thanks, Also found an FAQ from MS:                                                                
 What about two ESPs on two different disks?
ESP partitions can be replicated for high-availability configurations.
Replication must be done manually and the contents must be synchronized manually when using software volumes. 
Hardware vendors may provide additional solutions for high availability. ESP partitions cannot be mirrored.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-and-gpt-faq