# How to recover windows boot option after installed fedora 38 on another disk

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub

I just installed fedora 38 on my extra ssd, but after installed it. I can't boot into my windows 10. Even the windows boot manager option disappear from bios.

```
lsblk --fs
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL                 UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
zram0                                                                                              [SWAP]
nvme1n1                                                                                            
├─nvme1n1p1 vfat   FAT32                       B0AA-387C                             581.4M     3% /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2 ext4   1.0                         78b3793a-1f30-4853-82d3-40407562bf2d  725.4M    19% /boot
└─nvme1n1p3 btrfs        fedora_localhost-live 31d7451f-1ce2-4e49-ba3e-0057b0fb35a9  458.7G     1% /var/lib/docker/btrfs
                                                                                                   /home
                                                                                                   /
nvme0n1                                                                                            
├─nvme0n1p1                                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p2 ntfs                               FCF8DFD1F8DF87F2                      173.7G    63% /run/media/ggfan/FCF8DFD1F8DF87F2
└─nvme0n1p3 ntfs                               EEA427AEA427786B
```

I found some post about how to manually add it to grub, but I can't even get UUID.

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WDS500G2B0C-00PXH0                  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7786EC75-6248-4107-BA9B-8C9292F47CC3

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1    2048   1230847   1228800   600M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2 1230848   3327999   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme1n1p3 3328000 976773119 973445120 464.2G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3ACA63D9-7717-437D-8BE1-6E9B5237F430

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2     34816 975589115 975554300 465.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 975589376 976771071   1181696   577M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/zram0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

os-prober can't detect windows too:

```
root@fedora ~]# os-prober 
/dev/nvme1n1p3:Alpine Linux v3.16:Alpine:linux:btrfs:UUID=31d7451f-1ce2-4e49-ba3e-0057b0fb35a9:subvol=root/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/8b4f9bbe1c7d0f91cbe8165298a5cc5adec61af301ca6d4ce85a816feab74105
```

EFI folder is found in /dev/nvme0n1p2 which has NTFS file system
[image]

Comment: Assume you are right about windows installed in legacy mode, is there any way still can boot into it ? @ChanganAuto

Comment: I was wrong (deleted comment). GPT means UEFI mode for Windows, strictly. Now, knowing that the ESP couldn't have been in the Samsung SSD, I think you had the original ESP in the WDC and while installing Fedora you probably deleted it, wasn't it? Well, if so you deleted the Windows bootloader and now you have to boot Windows installation media and perform a boot repair.

Comment: The proper installation method should've used the existing ESP for Fedora as well and probably the partitioning had to be done manually (if I remember correctly  Fedora isn't as user friendly as Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives). In any case "not familiar with boot stuff" is NOT an option.

Comment: I wonder where the original EFI partition should have been. On `nvme0n1` is no space left for a further partition. Also I doubt, that the EFI partition on `nvme0n1` is the original one of Windows. (`nvme0n1p1` is the "Microsoft Reserved" partition and must persist) — (1) How Windows had been installed? (2) Has `nvme1n1` been newly installed to the system for the fedora installation? And did you boot to Windows afterwards? (3) Please issue `efibootmgr -v` and post the results (4) Show the content of the EFI-partition.

Comment: see this: https://superuser.com/questions/1346293/im-confused-i-dont-have-an-efi-partition-in-my-drive-but-i-can-boot-windows it seems a separate EFI partition is not necessary  @dodrg thanks for help, I will update information when I got home, as it's my home PC.

Comment: Please also have a look at both NTFS partitions. Regarding the link to 1346293 they might (`nvme0n1p3` surely will) contain a directory `EFI`. // Please note the typo in my last comment:  *"EFI partition on `nvme0n1`"* should name the second disk *`nvme1n1`*.

Comment: @dodrg see my edits, EFI folder is found, can you give me some advices to setup dual boot  ?

Comment: @dodrg thanks for helping, problem fixed by recreating the EFI partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EFI Partition is missing, so I recreated it by using windows install media.

by pressing `shift + f10` when choose language wazard appears, enter command prompt then:

```
diskpart

list disk
// choose disk carefully 
select disk 0

list partition
// choose partition carefully 
select partition 2
// shrink another partition to give ESP sapce
shrink desired =600

// now create the ESP 
create partition efi

// format it as FAT32
format fs=fat32 quick


assign letter=Y

exit

// fill ESP with EFI files...
bcdboot c:windows /s Y:
```

Comment: Nice to hear, you have a solution! – Please acknowledge your answer as accepted to close the question.